# tab doesnot show tab name in ginger bread

Tags: android

I am developing an application that uses tabs.

The problen is:  in devices with API level 15 or higher it is working fine, but in lower than API 15 (for ex GingerBread) it is not working.

Problem: In tabs, it dosenot show the text that I have written on tabs, it just show blank tabs.
You can see the images

**correct image : we can see the tab names "Tracker"," Call Logs", "STD codes" and "ISD Codes"**
              [image]

**Problem Image  tab name not shown in this image(in gingerbread)**
[image]

As you can  see in this image tab names names are not shown.

My code is below

main.xml

```
         <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<TabHost android:layout_width="fill_parent"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:id="@android:id/tabhost"

>
<TabWidget
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:id="@android:id/tabs"

/>
<LinearLayout 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"

        >
 <FrameLayout
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
 >


 </FrameLayout>


   </LinearLayout>

</TabHost>
```

My activity file is

```
      public class MobileNumberTrackerTabbedHomeActivity extends TabActivity {
        /** Called when the activity is first created. */
        TabHost tabHost;

        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
        {
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                setContentView(R.layout.main);

                tabHost=getTabHost();
                //First Tab
                TabSpec tab1=tabHost.newTabSpec("Tracker");
                tab1=tab1.setIndicator("Tracker");
                Intent intentNumberTracker =new Intent(this, NumberTrackerActivity.class);
                tab1=tab1.setContent(intentNumberTracker);

                TabSpec tab2=tabHost.newTabSpec("STD Codes");
                tab2=tab2.setIndicator("STD Codes");
                Intent intentSTDCode=new Intent(this,STDCodeFinderActivity.class);
                tab2=tab2.setContent(intentSTDCode);

                TabSpec tab3=tabHost.newTabSpec("ISD Codes");
                tab3=tab3.setIndicator("ISD Codes");
                Intent intentISDCode=new Intent(this,ISDCodeFinderActivity.class);
                tab3=tab3.setContent(intentISDCode);


                TabSpec tab4=tabHost.newTabSpec("Call Logs");
                tab4=tab4.setIndicator("Call Logs");
                Intent intenCallLogs=new Intent(this,ShowCallLogsActivity.class);
                tab4=tab4.setContent(intenCallLogs);

                tabHost.addTab(tab1);
                tabHost.addTab(tab4);
                tabHost.addTab(tab2);
                tabHost.addTab(tab3);


        }
```

}

What should I do so that tabs worh fine with all APIs
Please suggest a solution

thanks

Answer (score 0):

It should be like,

```
//First Tab
      TabSpec tab1=tabHost.newTabSpec("Tracker");
      tab1.setIndicator("Tracker");
      Intent intentNumberTracker =new Intent(this, NumberTrackerActivity.class);
      tab1.setContent(intentNumberTracker);
```

for each Tab, instead of

```
//First Tab
      TabSpec tab1=tabHost.newTabSpec("Tracker");
      tab1=tab1.setIndicator("Tracker");
      Intent intentNumberTracker =new Intent(this, NumberTrackerActivity.class);
      tab1=tab1.setContent(intentNumberTracker);
```

By assigning everytime `tab1 = new content/setting` you are over-writing the previous set fields.